# Python strange behavior with for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration

I am a beginner learning python. 
I have a problem with this for loop.

I am trying to a search loop for pc  to track the move made by the player (human) and to anticipate the next move in a tic tac toe game.

As a result,  I create a for loop to append the moves made by the player(human) but something strange happens

```
    lst = [ [ "X",[], [] ],
    [ [], "X", []   ],
    [ [], "X", []   ] ]
    temp_lst = []
    for i in lst:
        lst_1 = []
        for j  in i:
            if j  == "X":
            lst_1.append(lst.index(i))
            print(lst.index(i))
            lst_1.append(i.index(j))
            print(i.index(j))
        temp_lst.append(lst_1)

  print (temp_lst)
```

The results on my IDLE is:

```
    0
    0
    1
    1
    1
    1
   [[0, 0], [1, 1], [1, 1]]
```

Note that the position of the "X" IN THE MIDDLE  and the "X" int the last list is the same which would not be.  This is my problem. Note that when I change the lst to:

```
     lst = [ [ "X",[], [] ],
    [ [], "X", []   ],
    [ [], [], "X"  ] ]       

   result: [[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]]
```

The result from python  shows the correct position of the last "X" but in the previous one it  gave the strong position for the last "X"

Please help  thank you

Comment: Your expected output for the last iteration is [1,2]?

Comment: Your code's indentation is wrong. This is important in python and does change what your code outputs. You should correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jeff Meatball Yang said index works so that it find first occurance in list. I would do something like that

```
lst = [["X", [], []],
   [[], "X", []],
   [[], "X", []]]
temp_lst = []

for i in range(len(lst)):
    lst_1 = []
    for j in range(len(lst[i])):
        if lst[i][j] == "X":
            lst_1.append(i)
            print(i)
            lst_1.append(j)
            print(j)
    temp_lst.append(lst_1)

print (temp_lst)
```

The result of that code is: [[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 1]]

Answer (score 1):

In the outer loop, on the last iteration, you are testing for the index of the literal array: `[[],["X"],[]]`. So Python finds the first one by equality: which is the same as the second item.